# Will downloading typescript types help in javascript projects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I read that vscode behind the scenes relies on typescript definitions along with JSDoc. So will me downloading typescript definitions help in the intellisense even though I am using pure javascript and not typescript in my project?

eg: will downloading and installing `npm --save-dev @types/<some_library>` help with the intellisense for that library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is **no** in regards to the auto completion of vs code since you may not be able to import those types in your `js` files.

As a side note, you can use typescript to check javascript for type confirmity. Therefore you just need to add the following flags to your tsconfig `compilerOptions` after initializig one in your repo.

```
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true
```

VS Code certainly will point out type errors for simple types but may not find any errors in any third party lib.